# Ag Grid error : unable to find bean reference focusController

Tags: ag-grid

We are trying to integrate AgGrid feature Range Selection with Fill Handle but getting below exception  =>index.js:1 ag-Grid: unable to find bean reference focusController while initialising clipboardService

```
Uncaught TypeError:       this.mouseEventService.getNormalisedPosition is not a function
at FillHandle.onDrag (fillHandle.js:54)
at Object.onDragging (abstractSelectionHandle.js:40)
at DragService.onCommonMove (dragService.js:173)
at DragService.onMouseMove (dragService.js:190)
```

Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: Can you provide more info, whether it is javascript , angular, vue, react

Comment: it looks like you're trying to call a native event method, but failing because you're being passed with a [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) (which only has a subset of the native API methods). does that help?